# Does anyone know of articles on knockout validation

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using Knockout and the [project Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) 
seems a great way to add validation, but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know any good articles that have been written on it?

The examples are a bit confusing like, does your main object that contains observables have to be a validatedObservable and if not, how do you validate the things. Then in the configuration examples there's a line that says ko.applyBindingsWithValidation but isn't mentioned anywhere else.

What I'm really looking to do is have a view that does a foreach on an observable array. Each item would then have it's own save button and would need to validate.

Thanks

Comment: You should post example code of the objects within the observable array. From there I can write up a more concrete example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach to achieve your goal:

First setup the configuration for validation and enabled it with this tid bit:

```
    ko.validation.init({
        grouping: { deep: true, observable: false }
    });
```

Now there are other configuration options you can use as you see fit [HERE](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration). I only mention the `grouping` option because it is vital if you want your objects (which could be potentially nested/hierarchical) to recursively traverse through and identify all objects within it are valid.

Then I generally use the following approach to validating my models - I take advantage of a grouping function like so:

```
var myModel = { 
    Id: 0,
    FirstName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
    LastName: ko.observable('').extend({ required: true }),
    DateOfBirth: ko.observable('').extend({ date: true }),
    Errors: ko.validation.group(this),
    isValid: ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Errors.length == 0;
    });
};
```

Or using a functional declaration approach:

```
function myModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = 0;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable('').extend({ required: true });
    self.LastName = ko.observable('').extend({ required: true });
    self.DateOfBirth = ko.observable('').extend({ date: true });

    self.Errors = ko.validation.group(self);

    self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Errors.length == 0;
    });
};
```

`ko.validation.group(obj)` is the key to this approach. This function will recursive traverse the object passed in and identify every validatable object within it. Then it wraps them into a validatedObservable and the result is an observableArray that is populated with the error messages generated by any validators that fail validation.

So now we can write a save function like so, where the button receives the model or if you prefer to define the save method within the object itself, that works too:

```
var parentModel = {
   Save: function(model) {
      if (model.isValid())
         //perform save
      else {
         //do whatever
         //forces all error msgs associated to display in UI
         model.Errors.showAllMessages(); 
      }
   }
};
```

**Make sure to perform `ko.applyBindings(model)` after `ko.validation.init()` is invoked and your model is ready with validators**

Hopefully this gives you something to get you started! Here is a [comprehensive example](http://jsfiddle.net/ericbarnard/KHFn8/) that got me on the right track when I was first starting to use this plugin.